# (JAVA) How to differentiate 2d object

Tags: java

one simple question. I try to use graphic 2d to make objects . My question is how can we differentiate the variable between 2 object.
For example the below code;

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
         r1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 50, 30);
         r2 = new Rectangle(450, 10, 50, 30);
        
    
           g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 30);
              
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(450, 10, 50, 30);
            
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     if (r1.intersects(r2)) {..............
}
```

from above code,i have 2 rectangle variable r1 and r2, and i can do "if (r1.intersects(r2))"
in the actionPerformed method.

But how about below code when using Graphic2d, how can i differentiate between these 2 triangle, so that it can fit into "if (r1.intersects(r2))", as only one variable "lukis" only exist and it is used to make 2 triangle. Thank you.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    Graphics2D lukis = (Graphics2D) g;
    
    int[] x = {100, 200, 300};
    int[] y = {300, 100, 300};
    
    lukis.setColor(Color.RED);
    lukis.drawPolygon(x, y, 3);
    
    int[] x1 = {600, 700, 800};
    int[] y1 = {300, 100, 300};
    
    lukis.setColor(Color.RED);
    lukis.drawPolygon(x1, y1, 3);
}
```

Comment: Don't use the drawPolygon() or fileRect(...) methods. Instead you can use the `draw(Shape)`  or `fill(Shape)` methods. So you can create two `Shape` variables to draw your triangles. Then you can use the `contains(...)` method of the `Shape` API. See [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for an example of using a Shape object for your triangles.

Comment: (1-) cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/734752/java/java-graphic#3417140 and the same advice was given.